# java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap

Tags: android, appium

I keep getting this error for all my test cases:

```
> 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(java.util.function.Function, java.util.function.Function)'
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(java.util.function.Function, java.util.function.Function)'
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.makeW3CSafe(AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.java:40)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.\<init\>(AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.java:54)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:268)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.\<init\>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.\<init\>(AppiumDriver.java:90)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.\<init\>(AppiumDriver.java:102)
> at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.\<init\>(AndroidDriver.java:109)
> at com.example.dissertationdummyapp.AppiumTest.setUp(AppiumTest.java:70)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

This is my `AppiumTest.java` file:

```
package com.example.dissertationdummyapp;

// This sample code supports Appium Java client \>=9
// https://github.com/appium/java-client
import static org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.options.BaseOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.\*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class AppiumTest {

    private AndroidDriver driver;


@Before
public void setUp() {
var options = new BaseOptions()
.amend("platformName", "Android")
.amend("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2")
.amend("appium:platformVersion", "14.0")
.amend("appium:deviceName", "Pixel 7 API 34")
.amend("appium:udid", "emulator-5554")
.amend("appium:appPackage", "com.example.dissertationdummyapp")
.amend("appium:appActivity", ".MainActivity")
.amend("appium:noReset", "true")
.amend("appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages", true)
.amend("appium:nativeWebScreenshot", true)
.amend("appium:newCommandTimeout", 3600)
.amend("appium:connectHardwareKeyboard", true);

        private URL getUrl() {
            try {
                return new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        driver = new AndroidDriver(this.getUrl(), options);
    }
    
    
    //START OF TESTS
    
    //Login Page Tests
    @Test
    public void LoginPageError() {
        WebElement el9 = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Please fill in all the fields\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(el9.getText(), "Please fill in all the fields");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void LoginPageSuccess() {
        WebElement el5 = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[1]"));
        el5.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement el7 = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[2]"));
        el7.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement el8 = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.Button"));
        el8.click();
        WebElement el9 = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Welcome test\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(el9.getText(), "Welcome test");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void LoginPageSignUpButton() {
        WebElement signUpButton = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.className("android.widget.Button"));
        signUpButton.click();
        WebElement signUpMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Sign Up Screen\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(signUpMessage.getText(), "Sign Up Screen");
    }
    
    //SignUp Page Tests
    @Test
    public void SignUpPageSuccess(){
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[1]"));
        email.sendKeys("test@test.com");
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[2]"));
        username.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[3]"));
        password.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement cpassword = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[4]"));
        cpassword.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement signUpButton = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]"));
        signUpButton.click();
        WebElement successMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Welcome test\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(successMessage.getText(), "Welcome test");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void SignUpPageEmailError(){ //testing email field
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[1]"));
        email.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[2]"));
        username.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[3]"));
        password.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement cpassword = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[4]"));
        cpassword.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement errorMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Email address is invalid\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(errorMessage.getText(), "Email address is invalid");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void SignUpPageEmailPasswordsError(){ //testing passwords fields
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[1]"));
        email.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[2]"));
        username.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[3]"));
        password.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement cpassword = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[4]"));
        cpassword.sendKeys("tes");
        WebElement errorMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Email address and Password fields are incorrect\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(errorMessage.getText(), "Email address and Password fields are incorrect");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void SignUpPagePasswordsError(){
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[1]"));
        email.sendKeys("test@test.com");
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[2]"));
        username.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[3]"));
        password.sendKeys("test");
        WebElement cpassword = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[4]"));
        cpassword.sendKeys("tes");
        WebElement errorMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Welcome test\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(errorMessage.getText(), "Passwords do not match");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void SignUpPageLoginButton(){
        WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.className("android.widget.Button"));
        loginButton.click();
        WebElement loginMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Login Screen\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(loginMessage.getText(), "Login Screen");
    }
    
    //Success Page Tests
    @Test
    public void SuccessPageLogoutButton(){
        WebElement logoutButton = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.className("android.widget.Button"));
        logoutButton.click();
        WebElement loginMessage = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Login Screen\"]"));
        Assert.assertEquals(loginMessage.getText(), "Login Screen");
    }
    
    //END OF TESTS
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

and this is my build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.dissertationdummyapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.dissertationdummyapp"
        minSdk = 34
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.6")
    implementation("androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    testImplementation("io.appium:java-client:9.0.0") {
        exclude(group = "com.google.guava")
    }
    testImplementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.16.1")
    testImplementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre")
}
```

I don't understand why my Appium tests are refusing to be passed through. To my knowledge, the test cases are written correctly (other than using xpaths.) I know Appium works because the Appium-Inspector works.

Comment: did you find the problem? Can you please share the solution? Thx